# Junction/Simlink Causes plugin_url() to Return the Wrong URL

Tags: php, version-control, symlink, wordpress

I'm testing my plugin in various WordPress versions and using symbolic links for it. I use the tool called [Junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) for Windows. This way I just only need to edit the trunk files. However, WordPress does not seem to handle symbolic links very well.

For example, if I run a plugin with the following code.

```
<?php
/*
    Plugin Name: Junction/Simlink Test
*/
echo __FILE__ . '<br />';
echo plugins_url('junctiontest.php', __FILE__) . '<br />';
?>
```

and create a symbolic link, (this is for Windows)

> junction "z:\xampp\htdocs\wp34\wp-content\plugin\junctiontest2" "Z:\xampp\htdocs\wpcurrent\wp-content\plugins\junctiontest"

when I open the admin page of the test site with the url of `wpcurrent`, I get

```
Z:\xampp\htdocs\wpcurrent\wp-content\plugins\junctiontest\junctiontest.php
http://localhost/wpcurrent/wp-content/plugins/junctiontest/junctiontest.php
```

However, when I open the admin page of the test site with the url of `wp34`, I get

```
Z:\xampp\htdocs\wpcurrent\wp-content\plugins\junctiontest\junctiontest.php
http://localhost/wp34/wp-content/plugins/Z:/xampp/htdocs/wpcurrent/wp-content/plugins/junctiontest/junctiontest.php
```

This breaks the linked plugin.

So any suggestion to avoid this? I do not like to copy and paste the plugin into each directory every time I make a change in the trunk files.

I found this page: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/16953 It seems this is a known issue held by many plugin developers and it hasn't been solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a folder synchronization tool such as [DSYNCHRONIZE](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/).